# Python schedule persistence

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling

What is the correct way to have python [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (by daniel bader) persistently run. I currently run the job by having a terminal open, connected to a VM where the scripts actually run. There I run python "scheduler.py" - where scheduler.py has all the jobs.

But when the connection closes, or I close the terminal, the scheduler stops.

Any easy solutions to fix this?

Comment: Run a CRON job on the machine that needs to execute the job (if it's Linux/Unix), or use Windows Task Scheduler if it's Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options here. You are starting the process in your ssh session, but then killing the ssh session, which then kills the process.

One way to handle this, would be to have the VM run the script on startup. You could set the script as a service, so even if it goes down for some reason it will come back up. Read into `init.rc` for info on how launch a script at boot on linux. I'm not well-versed in Windows any more but I believe there is a way to do the same.

Another option is to keep the session open by connecting to it with `screen` or `tmux`. This article explains the problem some and gives you a few different ways to work around the issue: https://www.tecmint.com/keep-remote-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection/