# Python - Flask - Updating an API call based on a schedule

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, schedule

I am trying to refresh the results from an API call every 24 hours and feeding it into a flask app.
I was able to refresh the API call every 5 seconds as shown, however when the page is refreshed, the API call is invoked.

The needed result is to retrieve the content of an API call daily regardless of http requests.

Is there a method to restrict the API call on page refresh and only based on a given scheduled interval?

```
from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler
from flask import Flask

def api_call():
    """ Function for test purposes. """
    return ("API call")

sched = APScheduler()


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('main_page.html', title='Register',api_call = api_call())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sched.add_job(id = "scheduled task",func= api_call,trigger = 'interval',seconds = 5)
    sched.start()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this is by using the `schedule` library in Python to run a function at a specified time that updates the data that your API uses. Here's an example of how you could set this up:

```py
import schedule
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

def api_call():
    """ Function for test purposes. """
    return ("API call")

@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('main_page.html', title='Register', api_call=api_call())

schedule.every().hour.do(api_call) # schedule hourly

schedule.run_continuously()  # run in background

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, wouldn't this method also allow for the API to be invoked when the page is refreshed?

Comment: Yes that is a limitation of the code above, this is also the case in your code. You should look into slight modifications to the code above to have persistent scheduling. Check out this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317405/python-schedule-persistence. Hope this helps.